# Google Chrome extension - How to access an element and send a HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I haven't managed to find any good resources on Google Chrome extension development. Does anyone know of any blogs or resources that walks you through creating extensions?

I am trying to create a chrome extension that when I press the extension icon in the toolbar it will look through the webpage, retrieve certain elements and then send a HTTP request to the server as if the javascript that is sending the http request is part of the original page.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html

This is the Google documentation that covers almost everything a Chrome extension developer needs to know.

In particular you'll need to look at [content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) and [cross-origin XMLHttpRequests](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html).

Good luck!